# How to resolve code duplication in View for model instances filtering

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I trying to figure out how to resolve probably a very simple issue, but I would like to do it in an appropriate and Django consistent way.

Let's assume that we have an example model:

```
class ExmapleModel(Model):
    vote_up = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    vote_down = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def get_voting_count(self):
        return self.vote_up - self.vote_down
```

Ok and now I would like to create separate views on one template for ExmapleModel which will have for instance voting count higher than 500 and for all instances. Of course, I could create something like:

```
class ModelListView(ListView):
    model = ExmapleModel
    template_name = 'ExmapleModel_list.html'
```

and the second one:

```
class ModelListView(ListView):
    model = ExmapleModel
    template_name = 'ExmapleModel_list.html'

    queryset = ExmapleModel.objects.filter(get_voting_count()>300)
```

Assuming all the above, I would like to prevent repeating a lot of code for the above example, I have no idea how to user a get_voting_count() method for filtering and combining all of those things for the working package. If you have any ideas on how to combine it please help me.

On other hand should I use this logic within Model?

Comment: Not knowing that much about Django, couldn't you just create a `class BaseModelListView(ListView)` with the common code, and then subclass it for your two conditions?

Comment: Probably this is one of the most common ways how to prevent code duplication but still, we are putting logic within View instead of Model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolved:**

What kept me awake at night was much simpler than I thought. So basically to resolve filtering by computed fields I've created a Model manager for my model and in manager, I've added a filter in a voting variable as below:

```
def get_hot_deal(self, days, hot_result):
    voting = F('vote_up') - F('vote_down')
    hot_deals = Deal.objects.annotate(rate=voting).filter(
        rate__gte=hot_result,
        created_at__gte=datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days)
    )  
    return hot_deals
```